# Handling a file upload request with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to extract a XML file from a request that comes like this:

**Header:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MIME_boundary_314159265358979
```

**Raw:**

```
--MIME_boundary_314159265358979
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="result"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
</data>

--MIME_boundary_314159265358979
```

I found something similar at the session 17.10.5 on Spring documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

but on this request there is no "name" for the Content-Disposition. 
Any Suggestion for how to handle it on the web service?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE
          , consumes = "multipart/form-data")
      @ResponseBody
      @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
      String handleRequest(@RequestPart MultipartFile file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public ModelAndView dataloaderUploadFile(@RequestParam(required = true) final MultipartFile file)
{
String xml = new String(file.getBytes());
.....
}
```

Comment: I tried it before but it doesn't work I had to handle the whole request and parse it with my own method.